# Sample Projects on OPENGL

Tags: c++, opengl, projects

i need few sample code projects on openGL for beginners.. i tried googling..
but still i m seeking ur suggestion on this.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably one of the best site for learning opengl in C++:
http://nehe.gamedev.net/default.asp

Check out the opengl tutorials on the left

Comment: +1 Definitely the best resource by far, not just for c++ but pretty much any language.

Comment: yeah, i was going to start looking at it for my pet python project too. would have found it about 10 yrs back when i first looked into writing games... boy was that career path a fail.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for nehe: http://nehe.gamedev.net/

Answer (score 1):

You could try this: [The OpenGL Programming Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321552628) - the redbook

It's official publication for learning openGL. It's already the seventh edition concentrated on versions 3.0 and 3.1 of openGL (another edition for version 4.1 will be available soon). It covers the basics and gets into more advanced topics as well.

Or you could try these video tutorials: [videotutorialsrock.com](http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/)

These videos follow similar structure as the book I mentioned above. They introduce some general 3d graphics concepts and the appropriate openGL syntax. I think it is a nice first step for those new to both openGl and 3d graphics programming.

Answer (score 1):

nehe.gemdev is perfect but you can check mine [game](http://wblade.com/ogl/opengl.zip)
 from wblade.com

Answer (score 1):

Some small project may be a simple dice game for beginners for learning object formation, texturing and motion + carrying out calculations at the background and displaying result.

At a heigher level, there can be a tank game with the paths defined using formation of terrains etc... or a simple ball-collision game.

for reference, you can refer http://www.videotutorialsrock.com/ , it has sample codes for all these operations and the redbook.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to go through the book but you can get good examples from  http://nehe.gamedev.net/

You can also get few good codes free to downloads from the [www.openglprojects.in](http://www.openglprojects.in/), this site contains many of the good projects including the source code for it.